# Database.upsert( LIST, FALSE) returns for each Database.UpsertResult only CUSTOM validation errors when a record has both CUSTOM and SYSTEM errors

Tags: apex, validation, error-messages

I am wondering if the statement I posted as the title is correct and/or perceived as a normal flow of execution.

THE CONTEXT:

1. I've got an APEX method that is used from a Lightning Component to
   upsert Account and related Contact records.
2. I use the Database.upsert(LIST,FALSE) method to populate a
   List<Database.UpsertResult> with all my errors, and then format them
   in a list and send them back to the Lightning Component to be
   displayed.
   THE PROBLEM:
3. If the Account record violates both a CUSTOM validation error and a
   SYSTEM validation error, the getErrors() method of the
   Database.UpsertResult returns only the CUSTOM validation.
4. Furthermore, based on [Order of Execution salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318237&type=1), in theory
   FIRST the system validation rules are checked, THEN the custom
   validations are checked. This make me feel like I'm probably doing
   something wrong.

THE QUESTION:

Is there a way for all type of validation errors (custom/system) be returned in a single Database.upsert(LIST,false)?

SOME CODE:

```
        //errorsReturned: errors that will be returned to front end
        //errorsFound:errors found on the records submitted to the back end (here)
        List<ErrorData> errorsReturned=new List<ErrorData>();
        List<Database.Error> errorsFound;
        ErrorData errorData;
        Database.Error errorIter;
        

        //get from EACH contact upsertResult its errors on different fields and add them to the error list
        for(Integer i=0;i<contactsUpsertResults.size();i++){
            
            if(!contactsUpsertResults[i].isSuccess()){
                isUnsuccessfulUpsert=true;
                errorsFound=contactsUpsertResults.get(i).getErrors();
                System.debug('Found in total ('+errorsFound.size()+') errors.');
                for(Integer j=0;j<errorsFound.size();j++){
                    System.debug('found error on contact Id:'+contacts.get(i).Id+'\nmessage:'+errorsFound.get(j).getMessage());
                    errorIter=errorsFound.get(j);
                    errorData=new ErrorData();
                    errorData.message=errorIter.getMessage();
                    if(errorIter.getFields().size()==0){
                        continue;
                    }
                    errorData.fieldApi=errorIter.getFields().get(0);
                    errorData.recordId=contacts.get(i).Id;

                    errorsReturned.add(errorData);
                }
               
            }
        }
```